# In Docker image names what is the difference between Alpine, Jessie, Stretch, and Buster?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, docker-image, debian-jessie, debian-buster

I am just looking at docker images in https://hub.docker.com/_/node/

For every version, the images are categorized into Alpine, Jessie, Stretch, Buster etc. What's their meaning?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Those are the names of the OS in the container in which Node will be running.

Alpine is for Alpine Linux, Jessie and Stretch are versions of Debian. If you scroll down on the documentation link you provided, you'll find a section describing what Alpine is and why you might want to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Totally missed the "How to use this image" section.

Comment: So on what OS does a container using the node:latest image run on ?

Comment: It's currently coming from Debian Stretch, but could be updated in the future: https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/node/local/latest.md. I got to that link from the Node image page on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/_/node

Comment: If you're using `node:latest`, the assumption is that you want the latest version of Node and don't care what OS you're running on. If you really care about the OS, it would be preferable to use an image with the OS in the image tag.

Answer (score 291):

In docker-Context here are the important informations you need.

1. **Alpine**
   Url: https://alpinelinux.org/
   Imagename: `alpine`
   Shorty: Its very small.
   Packagemanger: `apk`
   Shells: `/bin/sh`
   Size: Few MBs - current tag needs 2.7MB
2. **Jessie** aka Debian 8
   Url: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianJessie
   Imagename: `debian:jessie`
   Shorty: [No LTS anymore](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS)
   Packagemanager: `apt`
   Shells: `/bin/bash`
   Size: ~50mb
3. **Stretch** aka Debian 9
   Url: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch
   Imagename: `debian:stretch`
   Shorty:  LTS is running out
   Packagemanager: `apt`
   Shells: `/bin/bash` and [many more](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/shells/)
   Size: ~40mb
4. **Buster** aka Debian 10
   Url: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster
   Imagename: `debian:buster`
   Shorty:  All what you need, but newer
   Packagemanager: `apt`
   Shells: `/bin/bash` and [many more](https://packages.debian.org/buster/shells/)
   Size: ~50mb
5. **Bullseye** aka Debian 11
   Url: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBullseye
   Imagename: `debian:bullseye`
   Shorty: All what you need, but newer
   Shells: `/bin/bash` and [many more](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/shells/)
   Size: ~50mb
6. **Bookworm** aka Debian 12
   Url: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBookworm
   Imagename: `debian:bookworm`
   Shorty: Newest debian
   Shells: `/bin/bash` and [many more](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/shells/)
   Size: ~50mb
7. **Ubuntu** based on debian
   Url: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu
   Imagename: `ubuntu`
   Shorty:  All what you need
   Packagemanager: `apt`
   Shells: `/bin/bash` and more
   Size: ~25mb

Comment: You can find a list of Debian releases and their end of life (EOL) dates here: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases